# MySQL Database Layout/Modelling/Design Approach / Relationships

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Scenario: Multiple Types to a single type; one to many.
So for example:

parent multiple type: students table, suppliers table, customers table, hotels table

child single type: banking details

So a student may have multiple banking details, as can a supplier, etc etc.

**Layout Option 1** students table (id) + students_banking_details (student_id) table with the appropriate id relationship, repeat per parent type.

**Layout Option 2** students table (+others) + banking_details table. banking_details would have a parent_id column for linking and a parent_type field for determining what the parent is (student / supplier / customers etc).

**Layout Option 3** students table (+others) + banking_details table. Then I would create another association table per parent type (eg: students_banking_details) for the linking of student_id and banking_details_id.

**Layout Option 4** students table (+others) + banking_details table. banking_details would have a column for each parent type, ie: student_id, supplier_id, customers_id - etc.

**Other?** Your input...

> *My thoughts on each of these:*
>
> 1. Multiple tables of the same type of information seems wrong. If I want to change what gets stored about banking details, thats also several tables I have to change as opposed to one.
> 2. Seems like the most viable option. Apparently this doesnt maintain 'referential integrity' though. I don't know how important that is to me if I'm just going to be cleaning up children programatically when I delete the parents?
> 3. Same as (2) except with an extra table per type so my logic tells me this would be slower than (2) with more tables and with the same outcome.
> 4. Seems dirty to me with a bunch of null fields in the banking_details table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going any further: if you do decide on a design for storing banking details which lacks referential integrity, please tell me who's going to be running it so I can never, ever do business with them. It's that important. Constraints in your application logic *may* be followed; things happen, exceptions, interruptions, inconsistencies which are later reflected in data because there aren't meaningful safeguards. Constraints in your schema design *must* be followed. Much safer, and banking data is something to be as safe as possible with.

You're correct in identifying #1 as suboptimal; an account is an account, no matter who owns it. #2 is out because referential integrity is non-negotiable. #3 is, strictly speaking, the most viable approach, although if you *know* you're never going to need to worry about expanding the number of entities who might have banking details, you could get away with #4 and a `CHECK` constraint to ensure that each row only has a value for *one* of the four foreign keys -- but you're using MySQL, which ignores `CHECK` constraints, so go with #3.

Index your foreign keys and performance will be fine. Views are nice to avoid boilerplate `JOIN`s if you have a need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. By the way, not a real world example - was just for discussion purposes :)